# Inbox typo "exampe comment"

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox, spelling, documentation

I just received an inbox notification for an "exampe comment" (sic):

[image: exampe comment (sic)]

That should be "example comment".

Comment: Prety sue thas jut a tyo. Thans fr te repot.

Comment: [tag:status-bydesign] :)

Comment: Congrats on [1234 rep](http://imgur.com/a/9mrPE) by the way!

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ Not any more…

Comment: @gerrit oh well, at least I screenshotted.

Answer (score 2):

I ... don't think I can top [Tim Post's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290770/inbox-typo-exampe-comment#comment944016_290770). Fix going live in the next build. :)

Comment: Don't you mean "Fix going ive"? ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I do, but Tim aready made that joke and I fet weird copying it. ;)

Comment: heh, lo... so it was your bug to begin with? ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I wish. But in reality you should thank Kevin Montrose for this one.

Comment: who? Obviously you mean Kevn Montrse! ;) (sorry... Just... Can't... Resist...)